# JSON stringify with variables and array

Tags: arrays, json, ajax

I've this code:

```
var dic = "[";
    for (var i = 0; i < aelem.length; i++) {
        dic += "{Key:" + aelem[i].value + ",Value:" + belem[i].value + "}"
        if (i < aelem.length - 1)
            dic += ",";
    }
    dic += "]";

    var pData = JSON.stringify(
        {
            'Index': elem[0].value, 'Tag': elem[1].value,
            'DicRule': dic
        }
    );
```

But it isn't working. In result Index and Tag is field, but DicRule is empty.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` already serializes for you. Why are you serializing `dic` yourself?

Comment: I don't know serialize a array dynamically

Comment: Nothing different from normal objects/arrays: `var dic = []; for (var i = 0; i < aelem.length; i++) { dic.push({Key: aelem[i].value, Value: belem[i].value}); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
var dic= [];
    for (var i = 0; i < aelem.length; i++) {

        dic.push({
            Key: aelem[i].value,
            Value: belem[i].value
        });
    }       
    var pData = JSON.stringify(
        {
            'Index': elem[0].value, 'Tag': elem[1].value,
            'DicRule': dic
        }
    );
```